# How to detect if client intentionally left Room in Google Play Games Real-time Multiplayer?

Tags: android, google-play-services, multiplayer, google-play-games

Here is a multiplayer game and I need to display two notifications to player: first when rival disconnected due to some networking problems, and second - when he left game intentionally. 
Room is created with auto-match criteria (max players - 2). And each time when one of the players left game due to network problems or intentionally `RoomStatusUpdateListener` callbacks called in the next order:
`onDisconnectedFromRoom`, `onPeerLeft`, `onPeersDisconnected`.

So I show notification in `onDisconnectedFromRoom` callback, the problem is you can't detect if it was network problem that happened to rival or he left intentionally. `Participant.getStatus()` returns `STATUS_JOINED`.

So, how to detect if client left room intentionally?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can send game data between the clients. So just in case a player wants to left the game,
send a message that this specific user will disconnect now to all other players.

best whishes, Steve.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I thought about this option, but maybe it's possible without extra message.